# Call function when child dialog window is closed in Qt

Tags: c++, database, qt, n-tier-architecture

After trying a multitude of combinations I'm unable to get Qt to call a function in my main window dialog when another dialog is closed.

I looked and tried a few things with signal and slot but to no avail:
`QObject::connect( edit_dialog, SIGNAL( finished(int) ), this, refresh_table() );`

In short I've got a table that displays data from a custom container. The edit_dialog enables the editing of values and sending the changes directly to the database through a set of external functions (they work). But once that dialog is closed I would like to have the table be reloaded with the updated data from the container which pulls it from the database.

Db->Container->GUI table

I realize Qt has native libraries for read/write to DBs but that's no good for my purpose. I need a way to automatically call the `refresh_table()` function which I've tried putting inside the 'public slots' without any more success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually have to connect the refresh table function to a `SLOT( )`

```
connect( edit_dialog, SIGNAL( finished(int) ), this, SLOT( refresh_table() ) );
```

Other than that there seems to be nothing wrong with your approach.

You can also create your own signal and connect it to the refresh_table() function by using for example the on click event of a "Ok" , "Cancel" Button in that dialog and calling

`emit ownSignal( );`

in it.

Comment: created my own in the end (`signals: void hasUpdated();` in the class declaration) and emitted that. Worked like a charm, thanks for that.